# SQL Server - Reasons for OPTION (FAST N) to choose other execution plan

Tags: sql-server

What is the reason behind this behavior for a table with ~300,000,000 rows

Following query execution takes 1 sec to complete:

```
SELECT * FROM "DB_NAME"."dbo"."TABLE" 
WHERE (("G_L Account No_"= 11200)) AND
(("Posting Date">= '2001-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND
"Posting Date"<='2020-02-27 00:00:00.000')) AND
(("Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group"= '3475')) AND
(("Global Dimension 1 Code"= '8204' )) and 
"Entry No_"< 298815528
ORDER BY "Entry No_" DESC OPTION (FAST 1270)
```

And the same query with only change in last option of FAST to 1269 takes 5 min to complete.

```
SELECT * FROM "DB_NAME"."dbo"."TABLE" 
WHERE (("G_L Account No_"= 11200)) AND
(("Posting Date">= '2001-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND
"Posting Date"<='2020-02-27 00:00:00.000')) AND
(("Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group"= '3475')) AND
(("Global Dimension 1 Code"= '8204' )) and 
"Entry No_"< 298815528
ORDER BY "Entry No_" DESC OPTION (FAST 1269)
```

I found there is a different plan chosen for both but I can't understand why the plan changes due to number of rows to return with FAST. Original query from application has OPTION (FAST 100) but by testing I found the breakpoint is at 1270 when the query changes the execution plan.

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in double quotes? As for the question at hand it is because at the change point the sql engine decides that is easier to get rows with a different plan. See this question to see if it helps explain why this is happening. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/what-does-option-fast-in-select-statement-do

Answer (score 0):

`OPTION (FAST N)` sets a "row goal".

Smaller values of `N` encourage choices like nested loops that potentially can start streaming rows quicker and discourage blocking choices like sort merge joins or hash joins.

In your case I imagine the query optimiser has to choose between two different plans.

1. Seeking into a non covering index on `Entry No_ = 298,815,528` then scanning it in descending order and doing lookups to get the remaining columns and evaluate the other predicates in the `WHERE` clause.
2. Scan the table (clustered index or heap), evaluate the predicates and then sort all matching rows.

As option 1 does not require an initial step of identifying and sorting all rows that match the `WHERE` clause before delivering even the first row this has the potential to be faster to deliver a small number of rows. However this will lead to catastrophically bad overall performance as execution plan 1 will have to do in the order of 300 million look-ups before it stops executing and delivers the complete result (5 mins to execute this amount of lookups would be pretty quick so maybe the index does cover some other column(s) in the predicate to allow some rows to be eliminated without a lookup).

This type of scenario is easy to reproduce as in the following example.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(Id INT IDENTITY UNIQUE, OtherCol TINYINT)

INSERT INTO #temp(OtherCol)
SELECT TOP 10000000 CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) + 0 AS OtherCol
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2, sys.all_objects o3;

SELECT * 
FROM #temp
where OtherCol = 2
ORDER BY Id DESC 
OPTION (FAST 33);

SELECT * 
FROM #temp
where OtherCol = 2
ORDER BY Id DESC 
OPTION (FAST 32);

SELECT TOP 32 *
FROM #temp
where OtherCol = 2
ORDER BY Id DESC;

SELECT * 
FROM #temp with (index = 2)
where OtherCol = 2
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

### Execution Plans `FAST 32` vs `FAST 33`

[image]

The estimated plan costs for the four queries are below

```
+----------------------------+---------------------+
|           Query            | Estimated plan cost |
+----------------------------+---------------------+
| FAST 33                    |             22.1202 |
| FAST 32                    |              21.754 |
| TOP 32                     |             21.7579 |
| Scan + Lookups whole table |             1682.01 |
+----------------------------+---------------------+
```

### Observations

- The `TOP 32` and `FAST 32` plans are costed basically the same - the `TOP` can stop executing once the 32nd matching row is found. The `FAST` plan must carry on executing and return the entire result **but this extra cost is ignored**
- Query 4 shows the estimated cost of performing this plan whilst taking into account the complete number of lookups that the  `FAST 32` plan will perform. So the `FAST 32` plan is costed at only `1.29%` of its "true" cost.
- Query 1 and 2 have very close estimated costs, this is the tipping point between the two plans where the estimated costs of performing the required lookups to deliver the first `33` rows would exceed that of just reading the whole table and sorting the matching results.
- In this case the tipping point is quite low as the `where OtherCol = 2` predicate is fairly selective (`1/256`). This means the expected number of lookups needed before finding 32 matching rows is around `32 * 256 = 8,192` (SQL Server assumes that rows matching the condition will be distributed evenly throughout the table) and conversely the amount of data to sort is estimated as relatively low at `10000000/256` rows. If the predicate is made less selective the tipping point will be higher.